# JsonFormat com LocalDateTime springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, java-11

Olá, estou tentando gravar no banco somente a hora do atributo da minha entity, coloquei o @JsonFormat(pattern = "HH:mm:ss") mas da erro quando vai gravar

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "19:47:11": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '19:47:11' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 19:47:11 of type java.time.format.Parsed; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "19:47:11": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '19:47:11' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 19:47:11 of type java.time.format.Parsedat [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 10, column: 20] (through reference chain: br.com.lucas.entity.Acao["entrada"])]
```

pesquisando ao ver esse erro coloquei a anotação @JsonDeserialize, porém sem sucesso mas se eu deixar assim @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") ele grava, lógico passando a data junto mas queria somente a hora:minuto:segundo. Alguém já passou por esse problema e poderia falar como?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeira coisa, se você precisa apenas de hora, minuto e segundo, utilize LocalTime e não LocalDateTime, conforme a documentação https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html

2 - Estou utilizando o lombok nesse código de exemplo e alguns conceitos de imutabilidade, você pode deserializar a data da seguinte forma

Deserializador

```
public class DateDeserializer{
    private DateDeserializer() {
        super();
    }

    public static LocalTime localTime(String date) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
        return LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
    }
}
```

```
@Value
@With
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Acao.JacksonBuilder.class)
@Builder(builderClassName = "JacksonBuilder")
public class Acao {

   LocalTime entrada;


@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class JacksonBuilder {

       LocalTime entrada;

       public JacksonBuilder dataVencimentoReal(String entrada) {
            this.entrada = DateDeserializer.localTime(entrada);
            return this;
        }
  }
}
```